# Call value from key stores in Redis using phpredis

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I using Phpredis and am trying to get information from the following key called "statHistory" I am new to redis and not sure how to call each value individually. I am able to connect to redis using php and have tested it using the ping command. It has been two days of testing and I still cant get it to call properly.
Key Name: statHistory
http://pastebin.com/pXz5d0zf
image of redis-commander
http://postimg.org/image/pusnghk9n/

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand, you want to retrieve a (for example) a nested key value from the original key "statHistory" ?

If so, consider using a LUA script to

1. Get the "statHistory" key
2. Json.encode it
3. Access any of the keys in an array fashion

For example:

```
local myKey = redis.call("GET", "statHistory")
local json  = cjson.decode(myKey)
return json['algos']['scrypt']['workers'] -- will return "0.00 KH"
```

Or directly...

```
local json = cjson.decode(redis.call("GET", "statHistory"))
return json['algos']['scrypt']['workers'] -- will return "0.00 KH"
```

Check the docs for using stored procedures in LUA, [EVAL](http://redis.io/commands/eval)

Hope this helps!